# curl - selecting specific cookie value from cookie-jar file

Tags: php, curl, cookies

How do you select the value of a specific cookie from a cookie-jar file for future requests?

I need to submit a form on a website that requires that the current sessionId be passed as form data. The sessionId is set as a cookie on the login page.

First request (authentication)

```
curl -d "username=my_user&pass=my_pass" http://mywebsite.com/login.php -c, --cookie-jar  my-cookies
```

Second request (form submit)

```
curl -d "sessionId=jk5lkdr7cdqkn1ptqa0rmndbr7&formField1=abc&formField2=def" http://mywebsite.com/getReport.php -b, --cookie my-cookies
```

In the above request data, I've manually copied the session id from the cookie file. The cookie file looks like this. (sessionId = PHPSESSID)

```html
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

mywebsite.com FALSE / FALSE 0 PHPSESSID jk5lkdr7cdqkn1ptqa0rmndbr7
.mywebsite.com TRUE / FALSE 1516507485 info crownandcaliber%40mediaiqdigital.com
.mywebsite.com TRUE / FALSE 1507867485 pref deleted
.mywebsite.com TRUE / FALSE 0 affiliate_flag Y3Jvd25hbmRjYWxpYmVyQG1lZGlhaXFkaWdpdGFsLmNvbQ%3D%3D
.mywebsite.com TRUE / FALSE 0 cookie name%3ATm8gYWR2ZXJ0aXNlciBuYW1lIGF2YWlsYWJsZQ%3D%3D%3B
```

Is there a way for me to progammatically pull the value of the PHPSESSID cookie which is set in the first request into the form data for the second request?

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov - don't need help keeping session alive; doing that by passing the session cookies in response. I'm looking to extract the _value_ of the session cookie and pass this as form data for request #2. (In addition to passing the whole cookie file.)

Comment: why don't you read it from file then?

Comment: awk 'NR==5' youfilewithcookie | awk {'print $7'} | (read sessId; yourculcommand here with $sessId)

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov good call - exactly what I was looking for. This resolved the issue!

Comment: please accept as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below reads a 5th line from a file *youfilewithcookie*, gets content of a 7th column and reads it in a variable called *sessId*.

```
awk 'NR==5' youfilewithcookie | awk {'print $7'} | (read sessId; yourculcommand here with $sessId)
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.  - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues.

Comment: Ended up going with this, in order to account for cases where the session cookie wasn't in line 5:  
`awk '/PHPSESSID/' jivox-cookies | awk {'print $7'} | ...`